# Regular Expression question Σ = {a, b}, what's the expression containing either ba or abb?

Tags: regular-expressions

So Σ = {a, b}, I need to find a regular expression representing all strings that contain either ba or abb. Here's what I got, but I wonder if it's correct.

(a*b*)*(baUabb*)(a*b*)*(ba*Uabb)(a*b*)*

It seems to be that it's a bit too long.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not just `(a|b)*(ba|abb)(a|b)*`?

Answer (score -1):

Note that the patterns `abb` and `ba` cover almost all possibilities for what can happen when you switch from one letter to the other. The only case that's not covered are strings like `aaaaaaab`, specifically with only a single `b` at the end. With that in mind, I was thinking

```
(a+b.+|b+a.*)
```

Which looks for either of the two following patterns:

- At least one `a`, then a `b`, then at least one more letter
- At least one `b`, then an `a`, then the rest of the string